# Is mylocationoverlay.enablemylocation() listening to location updates and drawing the current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I use `mylocationoverlay.enableMyLocation()` in order to show the user the current position.

I put this code in `OnCreate()`:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setClickable(false);
myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
mapView.postInvalidate();
```

and `OnResume()` I put `myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();` to enable the listener.

I can see the user position when I open the Wi-Fi (I am testing it at home). `enablemylocation` shows the user position and listens to updates from providers. But is it updating? I mean, if I move, will the blue dot start moving? Or do I have to do something else to update my position on map `onLocationChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

The myLocationOverlay.class implements the Interfaces [SensorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html), meaning that your location on the map will be automatically updated. 
You don't have to implementent any other listeners.